# how to load images one after the other in an ImageView instead of a viewflipper?

Tags: android, viewflipper, android-imageview

My project is to display a slideshow of images from the selected folder.

I have done the project using ViewFlipper. The problem I am stuck at is memory issues when loading more images to the viewflipper. I get a force close error if the folder contains more than 15 images.

```
Bitmap mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImageList.get(i));
    image.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

    viewFlipper.addView(image);
    System.gc();

    }
    viewFlipper.startFlipping();
```

How can this "**out of memory**" error be resolved, any other workarounds?
I heard somewhere that we can use a single imageview and just change the image during runtime. Any pointers as to how do I begin?
I also need to set the time-interval between image changes.

EDIT: Used ImageView instead of viewflipper and now I'm able to display a single image. How do I change the image in the Imageview after say 5 seconds? Code that I implemented in onCreate is:

```
 ImageView imgView01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
            File dir = new File("/sdcard/WallpapersHD/");
             File file[]=dir.listFiles();

             for (int i=0;i<file.length;i++) {


                 Drawable d = (Drawable) Drawable.createFromPath(file[i].toString());


                 imgView01.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Comment: If you are downloading a images from server then you have apply lazylist concept in your project It will download one images at a time.

Comment: No, my images are present in a folder in SDcard.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you show a new `Bitmap`, call [recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) on the previous image. This will free up space in memory, so you don't get the window leak error associated with bitmaps.

Comment: Since I'm using ViewFlipper, I'm unable to do this. I get a runtime error "Canvas : trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.bitmap" and the app force closes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for using a single `ImageView` then you have to use `postdelayed()` and `handlers()`.

Use this method in your `onCreate()`,

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        imageView.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        imageView.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        imageView.setBackgroudRsource(R.drawable.urImage);

    }
};
```

And now call these methods when required,

```
    imageView.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    imageView.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 1000); //1 sec delay to change images
```

Comment: I'm not able to get it properly working. I have edited the question above to provide what I have done until now. Tell me how do I proceed from there. Thanks again!